# No module named 'PySocks' but I have installed this module

Tags: python

Just like this picture below. I have an `ImportError`, but when I try to install this module, I found it existed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

PySocks is the name of the package. It installs two modules : `socks` and `sockshandler`. These are the ones you can import and use in your Python script.
Source : https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

Comment: It turns out that this is the case. Then I have already installed it.Thank you very much!